# youtube on iframe is not working

Tags: html, iframe

I tried to include the youtube in an iframe but it appears blank. This is the code I'm checking with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Why this is happening ? and what should I do to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337/38507). It will most likely have a message like:

**Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.**

Read more about [X-Frame-Options here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options):

> **The X-Frame-Options response header**
>
> The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>` or `<object>`. Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.
>
> [...]
>
> **SAMEORIGIN**
>
> The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.
>
> [...]
>
> In other words [...] if you specify SAMEORIGIN, you can still use the page in a frame as long as the site including it in a frame is the same as the one serving the page.

Long story short: Youtube doesn't want you to embed their site (note: I'm talking about webpages here, ***not*** video's!) and explicitly set a HTTP header to communicate that to browsers.

If you want to display/embed a *video* use their code that is below every video under Share » Embed.

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it results in showing just that video. Is there any way that I can display the whole page along with the suggested videos. Is there any other way that I can go for other than iframe.

Comment: '*Is there any way that I can display the whole page along with the suggested videos*': Even if you could (there are surely ways like proxying the page): you will probably violate the [Youtube TOS](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms). Your best bet is to use the [YouTube API's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) but I'm pretty sure it will be impossible (or very hard) to get *your visitors* suggested video's. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe allowfullscreen="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c0MZ2bTtBm0?autoplay=1&amp;autoplay=1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 1; display: block;" class="ms-slide-video"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```